# Angularjs function call with http

Tags: angularjs

how do i create a function that uses http.. i cannot get the data from the http.get
HTML

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="#/page" ng-click="getDataElement(x.bandid)">click!</a>
```

AngularJS

```
app.controller('bandsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$ionicLoading,$timeout){
    $scope.getDataElement = function(a){
        $http.get("http://wearemusicians.xxxxx.com/xxxxxx.php?id="+a)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.eachband = response.data.records;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: nope there is no error in console

Comment: Try `$http.get("http://wearemusicians.xxxxx.com/xxxxxx.php?id="+a).then(function (response) {$scope.eachband = response.data.records;}, function(error) {console.log(error);});` and see if there is any error in console

Comment: it is not showing any error in console

Comment: What is `x.bandid`? Where is it defined?

Comment: x.bandid is from the http.get result. the a link is under in the html ng-repeat

Comment: So x.bandit is not there yet.. No? Try to hardcode x.bandid and write some number instead,1 for example. If it will fetch some data, then I think you have instead of x.bandid put `$index`, if you are inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: there is already a value in x.bandid.

Comment: Try to write error handler and debug the code. See where debugger will go - success handler or error handler. What about network tab? Does it show the request?

Comment: So what about debugging and Network tab in devtools?

Answer (score 0):

** Remove href or make it #.
** then check this and check if you are assigning the right data.

```
app.controller('bandsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$ionicLoading,$timeout){

$scope.getDataElement = function(a){
$http.get("http://wearemusicians.xxxxx.com/xxxxxx.php?id="+a).then( function(response) {
  $scope.eachband = response.data.records;
  console.log(response.data.records);
  });
  return false;
};

});
```

If that does not work then try $apply while assigning:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.eachband = response.data.records;
  console.log(response.data.records);
})
```

Comment: i tried it and there is the data in $scope.eachband i have a problem in displaying it. i have already a html that has ng-repeat="x in eachband" but it still wont display

Comment: this is my page.html file that has a ng-repeat to read the data from the function


<ion-view view-title="Page" ng-controller="bandsCtrl">
 <ion-content ng-repeat="x in eachband">
 </br>
 <h1>{{x.bandname}}</h1>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Tried debugging? Second, can I see the data format/content?

Comment: this is the data/content in the console

[Object]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]

---1 is the value of the bandid

Comment: can you show me the array object structure. You are possibly referencing it wrong.

Comment: No, I want to see the array structure. and Where are you getting the bandid from. Can you put the plunkr?

Comment: the $scope.eachband has already values. but i cannot fetch it from my page.html i have commented above

Comment: i am getting the bandid from http.get this is the result .......... {"records":[{"bandid":"1","members":"JAY WAAA","bandname":"Kamikazee"}]}

Comment: i commented above the result of the http.

Comment: Ok, can you try response.records assigning and see if that resolves. Your ng-repeat and html does not seem to be the issue. Second, I do not think you can assign the x.bandid even before the result has been received. Can you?

Comment: Please update your post with the complete HTML structure. I see you have assigned an value to a function that is not yet defined and calling a http.get based on the value.

Comment: i dont think the issue is the bandid. because when i try to console.log from the function getDataElement. it does show the bandid = 1

Comment: I think you should put a plunkr. Its a small assigning issue or the place/way where you have call it.

Comment: i tried to ng-repeat it on same html and it will show the result.. while it wont show when i ng-repeat it on the other html file.

Comment: What is the controller of the external file?

Comment: the controller on my page.html is also bandsCtrl

Comment: so you have html file with a controller and then an external file with the same controller? Is it how it is placed? or is it differently structured?

Comment: yes. it is differently structed. my other page.html is used for page navigation

Comment: So, to rephrase you have single controller in two different html pages.... in such case same controller in two different pages will not work. try with one single template and then try writing a directive or better use two controllers and share data through service.